# Marquee text starts moving on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using [jquerymarquee](http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jquerymarquee/) and I want to have displayed the entire line of text at the beginning, and **scroll onMouseHover**, and when the line of text ends, the beginning of the text to appear after a while. Maybe there are other libraries that are able to do it ?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I tried several different libraries, but they all work in a similar way. I do not know JavaScrpit well and do not know how to do it.

Comment: @insict I found the solution. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work as you wanted. It is the same `library` which you are using.

I didn't start the `marquee onload`, and waited for the user to put his `mouse` over the `text`. And as the `user` puts his `mouse` over the `text`, `marquee` started.

You can check the demo here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/VJkxe/1/

Comment: You are great, I'm sorry but I forgot to add that the text has to go back to his place after removing the cursor from the text, and stop.

Comment: and how to imlements it's to web page? I do it like this: I put these three scripts in `<script src>` tan tag and pasting you wrote between `<script> </ script>` and the text put in `<div class="marquee-with-options"> </ div>` I'm doing well ?

Comment: hmm I do so and it does not work :/ can You try on your computer not in jsfiddle ?

Comment: Did you include jQuery latest version library on your page on the top of other scripts? and also you need to write all the below code inside $(document).ready(function(){ // all the code will come here   });

Answer (score 0):

in the example only..

```
$('.marquee-with-options').hover(function(e) {


});
```

dont use..property..pauseOnHover: true

you have to try some thing and if any problem occurs you have to ask here..